# Can I simulate duck typing in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a `responds_to?` kind of method in Dart without using mirrors.

My first attempt would be casting the object to `dynamic`:

```dart
try {
  final value = (obj as dynamic).value;
  doSomething(value);
} on NoSuchMethodError catch(e) {}
```

This check would be invoked very often and probably fail most of the time. Are there any performance implications with throwing/catching a lot of exceptions? (versus an if statement checking for a `bool` value like `respondTo(obj, 'value')`)

I explored another alternative using interfaces:

```
abstract class ValueBar {
  bool hasValue();
}

abstract class ValueFoo {
  bool hasValue();
}

class Foo implements ValueFoo {
  @override
  bool hasValue() => true;
}

class Bar implements ValueBar {
  @override
  bool hasValue() => false;
}

void main() {
  final foo = Bar() as ValueFoo;
}
```

Both interfaces share the same signature!

But I get:

```
Uncaught Error: CastError: Instance of 'Bar': type 'Bar' is not a subtype of type 'ValueFoo'
```

I know this is not possible, I would be interested to hear about other approaches.

Comment: you can't say `Bar` is a subtype of `ValueFoo` just because the underline implementation is the same as `Bar` ancestor (meaning `ValueBar`).

Comment: @TheMri fully agree with you